# sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index when compiling GWT 2.5

Tags: compiler-errors, java-6, weblogic12c, gwt-2.5

I am deploying GWT2.5 application on Weblogic version 12C and using JDK1.6

I am getting **sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index**

Below is the complete stacktrace.

```
 [echo] com.myapp.MyEntryPoint is out of date
 [java] Compiling module com.myapp.MyEntryPoint 
 [java] [ERROR] Unexpected
 [java] sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index
 [java]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:858)
 [java]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:765)
 [java]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:735)
 [java]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:146)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1002)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$INameEnvironmentImpl.findType(JdtCompiler.java:257)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$INameEnvironmentImpl.findType(JdtCompiler.java:235)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:122)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:181)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2460)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2181)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:113)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.resolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:282)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:179)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1167)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperInterfaces(ClassScope.java:958)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1011)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectMemberTypes(ClassScope.java:835)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1018)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:290)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:185)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:719)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:376)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:420)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:617)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:193)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:390)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:275)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:299)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:529)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:466)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:205)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:177)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:149)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
 [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:156)
```

Please help to identify what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the issue.

It was referring to the old gwt-servlet.jar

Once I replaced with the latest jar, build went successful.

Thank you.

Comment: I am using JDK1.8 and GWT 2.8.1 and i have added updated gwt-servlet.jar, but this error not resolved.